# How can I use 1 array with 2 different sizes using inheritance and constructors

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, constructor

I need to use a single array to track scores of a game where the indices are the levels of the game. In the parent class, the player is allowed 10 levels. In the child class, they are given 40 additional levels for a total of 50.

This chapter is on inheritance and they also cover constructors. Can a constructor in both parent class and child class change the size of a single array?

I have tried declaring the array to size 50, and then in each constructor allocating memory for the size that I need. [10] and [50] for parent and child classes respectively.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. From what I understand, you are reading a book about programming in Java. Can you post the requirements for the problem you are working on? Also, add some code snippets to your question to go along with your verbal explanation. Finally, you should read [ask] for some tips on improving your question in order to attract the information you seek.

Comment: I think everyone will suggest using a list, and in the real world, it definitely would be the correct use because of it's dynamic sizing, but I think the point of this assignment is to force us to use constructors to limit or allow the use of an array to specific needs per file.

Answer (score 0):

In Java arrays are not extendable, so you can not just "use 1 array with 2 different sizes". You probably want to use `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

There's also a question to ask: are you sure you need inheritance for this task? You could simply create an array of size you want:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(40);
```

But even that is not necessary. The list will grow as needed if there's no space left, so you should not take care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the constructor you should just be able redefine it like `array = new int[#]`

Also, maybe not an exact answer to your question, but you could use a List instead of an array. Java Lists are made to be resizable.

So instead of `int[]` , you could define it as `List<Integer>` and not even have to worry about the size.

Comment: I have tried this, but still to no avail. It is possible that there is something else wrong, so I'll post my code and see if you think it should work that way.

Comment: private int[] levelScore;  is how I defined the array.  levelScore = new int[10]; is how it is in the parent class constructor.  levelScore = new int[50]; is how it is in the child class constructor.  Should this work in this fashion or am I doing something incorrectly?                       Sorry for the horrible formatting. I can't get this thing to do any line breaks. .

Answer (score 0):

The lowest level in your hierarchy must give subclasses the option to define the array size.

For example:

```
package io.medev.stackoverflow;

public class Game1 {

    private final int[] levels;

    public Game1() {
        this(0);
    }

    protected Game1(int additionalLevels) {
        this.levels = new int[10 + additionalLevels];
    }
}
```

And the subclass:

```
package io.medev.stackoverflow;

public class Game2 extends Game1 {

    public Game2() {
        this(0);
    }

    protected Game2(int additionalLevels) {
        super(40 + additionalLevels);
    }
}
```

Like the others already mentioned, I would generally recommend to use a List instead of arrays in this case.